# Planck's law and CMBR

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, history, cosmic-microwave-background

Rereading statistical mechanics notes, I was recently struck by a fact that seemed very surprising to me. In the notes I am reading, one derives Planck's formula for the energy distribution of photons from a black body by assuming that electromagnetic radiation is a photon gas, then using the grand canonical ensemble. However, to me at least, the calculation seems somewhat crude, in that it feels like we are making many assumptions along the way—it does not even seem clear that a 'photon gas' is a good model for EM radiation. I was shocked to learn that this distribution is very nearly perfectly observed in nature, recently for example for cosmic microwave background radiation using a temperature of $2.7$ K. Was the experimental success of this seemingly very approximate calculation a great surprise to physicists at the time? Is there some intuitive physical reason why this calculation is so accurate, i.e. explaining why the 'photon gas' model is appropriate for EM radiation from a black body?

Comment: AFAIK, Planck during his law derivation (around 1900) still thought that the light thermal **emission** is quantized, but light itself is not. The idea of light quantization came with Einstein (1905) with the photoelectric effect paper. He has named those quanta later as photons.

Comment: I appreciate this fact, but surely the modern version of this calculation being accurate is surprising, regardless of how Planck derived it himself?

Comment: You shouldn't need the *grand* canonical ensemble for calculating the black-body spectrum, since photons have zero chemical potential (they can be emitted and absorbed freely), reducing the calculation just to the canonical ensemble.  Moreover, it's not clear to me where you are coming from with this question.  What *else* would the thermal electromagnetic spectrum in a cavity be, other than a gas of photons?

Comment: Sorry, the canonical ensemble. I guess what I am trying to ask is, typical other physics calculations I have seen in QM and beyond normally require a lot of extra terms and modifications to get close to experimental results, but here the distribution is already nearly perfect with a very simple calculation (without using any QFT even). Is this not surprising in some sense?

Comment: I think that this calculation works so well in part because it is dealing with many particles. Many macroscopic observables do not depend on the microscopic details of their components in the thermodynamic limit (e.g. The ideal gas law). From a mathematical perspective, non-fundamental microscopic details are erased when taking the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$ (e.g. The microcanonical, canonical and grand-canonical ensembles agree because of this limit ).